# MPG with PHP from MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database/website that tracks various things related to vehicles. I would like to get a report on MPG. Currently, when I enter a fuel receipt, it pulls the last miles entry and calculates a MPG and enters it in the database. But that creates errors if a receipt is entered out of order. And also creates inaccurate data if I have to go back in and correct a mileage entry.

Right now, when I run a report, I can get a report for a specific vehicle for a specified date range. How would I write my PHP to create the MPG field on the fly? What I don't know how to do is get it to look back one line to pull mileage one line back. My table is set up as

Fuel_ID (primary key)
Vehicle (secondary key)
Date
Miles
Gallons
Cost
Employee
MPG

As of right now, I don't really have much to post as to what I've tried because I am stuck at trying to get it to go back one line. Right now, the queries simply pull data from the table and display it in a table on a website.
And it looks like this.

```
<?php
include 'includes/conn.php';

  if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $vehicle = $_POST["vehicle"];
    $date1 = $_POST["date1"];
    $date2 = $_POST["date2"];
  }
//echo "<br><h2 class='display-5'>Fuel Report For ". $vehicle . "</h2><br>";
echo "<h2 class='display-6'> From ".$date1." To ".$date2. "</h2><br>";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Fuel 
        INNER JOIN Employees ON Fuel.Employee = Employees.Emp_ID
        INNER JOIN Vehicles ON Fuel.Vehicle = Vehicles.V_ID 
        WHERE Vehicle LIKE '$vehicle' 
        AND Date BETWEEN '$date1' AND '$date2' ORDER BY Date";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

$sqla = "SELECT SUM(Gallons) as gallons FROM Fuel WHERE Vehicle LIKE '$vehicle' AND Date BETWEEN '$date1' AND '$date2'";
$result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sqla);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2);
$gals = $row['gallons'];

$sqlb = "SELECT SUM(Cost) as cost FROM Fuel WHERE Vehicle LIKE '$vehicle' AND Date BETWEEN '$date1' AND '$date2'";
$result3 = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlb);
$row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result3);
$price = $row2['cost'];
echo "<br>";
$sqlc = "SELECT Bus_no FROM Vehicles WHERE V_ID = '$vehicle'";
$result4 = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlc);
$row3 = mysqli_fetch_array($result4);
$v_name = $row3['Bus_no'];

echo "<br><h2 class='display-5'>Fuel Report For ". $v_name. "</h2><br>";
# If we have at least one hit, we'll show it

echo "<table>";
echo "<tr>";
      echo  "<th>Date</th>";
      echo  "<th>Vehicle</th>";
      echo  "<th>Miles</th>";
      echo  "<th>Gallons</th>";
      echo  "<th>MPG</th>";
      echo  "<th>Price</th>";
      echo  "<th>Driver</th>";
      echo  "</tr>";
      if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while ($row1 = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr><td>" . $row1['Date'] . "</td><td>" . $row1['Bus_no'] . "</td><td>" . $row1['Miles'] . "</td><td>" . $row1['Gallons'] .  "</td><td>" . $row1['mpg'].  "</td><td>$" . $row1['Cost'] . "</td><td>" . $row1['FirstName'] . " " . $row1['LastName'] ."</td></tr>";
        }
      echo "<tr><td></td><td></td><td><b>Totals</b></td><td><b>".$gals.
      "</b></td><td></td><td><b>$".$price."</b></td><td></td></tr>";
      echo "</table>";
      }else {
        echo "<p>No result. The Database must be empty.</p>";
      }
?>
```

Comment: For the very first fuel receipt of a vehicule, how do you calculate the MPG?

Comment: It's not great coding, I'll admit. But the the first fueling on a new vehicle I have to manually enter the data into the database because it doesn't have a previous mileage and it will throw and error code. So the very first MPG is just entered as 0.00

Comment: If you know the initial mileage, you could store it in the Vehicles table. It would allow for the calculation of the first MPG.

Comment: Right. But what I am trying to do is calculate MPG on the fly. Let's say I want a fuel report for bus 7 between two date ranges. But I want the MPG field of the table to be calculated as the data is being pulled out of the database. This way it wouldn't matter if receipts weren't put into the database in order, because I could order the query by date.

Comment: Get the mileage from the last receipt before the start of the range, and the last receipt in the range. Get the sum of gallons for all the receipts in the range. Divide the difference in mileages by the sum.

Comment: @Barmar *"the last receipt before the start of the range"* What if there is none?

Comment: @Olivier They need to store the initial mileage somewhere, perhaps in the Vehicle table. Use that when there are no rows before the range.

Comment: I don't think I am explaining myself well. I have the initial mileage... that's not a concern. I have a query that says, "Go get this data for this vehicle for this date range". Lets say that returns 5 rows of data. Then my PHP says "for each row of data, create an html table that displays the data" What I want to know is how I make PHP take the mileage from row 2 of returned data, subtract mileage from row 1, and then loop so each row looks back to row before it for mileage.  Or would it just be easier add another field to the database that is the previous mileage?

Comment: @Barmar, Your solution would work to get an overall MPG for the range. But I would like to get a MPG for each receipt, for a number of reasons, but mainly to quickly and easily spot major errors in mileage or receipt inputs. Is there a way to loop so that for each row it would pull mileage from the row before?

Comment: Use the `LAG()` window function to relate each receipt with the previous one, so you can calculate the MPG for that period.

Comment: @Barmar  I just found LAG. I think that is my answer. I was trying to do it in PHP when I should have been looking to do it in MySQL. I am now learning how to correctly formulate my query with LAG. But that will be the correct answer in the end. Thanks a million!

Answer (score 1):

Thank you everyone. Barmar got me pointed in the right direction. The answer is to use the LAG function in MySQL rather than trying to do it in PHP. Here is the resulting code and it does exactly what I want it to do. It will generate a mpg value on the fly. And if a receipt gets entered out of order it will self correct when the missing receipt is added. Thanks a million.

```
$sql = "SELECT Date, Bus_No, Miles, Gallons, Cost, FirstName, LastName,
    ROUND((Miles - LAG(Miles) OVER (PARTITION BY Vehicle ORDER BY Date)) / Gallons, 2) AS mpg1 FROM Fuel 
    INNER JOIN Employees ON Fuel.Employee = Employees.Emp_ID
    INNER JOIN Vehicles ON Fuel.Vehicle = Vehicles.V_ID 
    WHERE Vehicle LIKE '$vehicle' 
    AND Date BETWEEN '$date1' AND '$date2' ORDER BY Date";
```